# Fail2ban jail does not detect failes (and does not ban)

Tags: debian

I tried to create an own filter for fail2ban to detect failed HTTP authentications tries. It does work when tested with fail2ban-regex but not in the running environment.

/etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
...
[DEFAULT]
bantime  = 600
...
[nginx-user-auth]
enabled = true
filter  = nginx-user-auth
port    = http,https
logpath = /var/log/nginx/error.log
backend = polling
maxretry = 6
...
```

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-user-auth.conf

```
[Definition]
failregex = user .*? password mismatch, client: <HOST>
        user .*? was not found in .*?, client: <HOST>
ignoreregex =
```

When testing:

```
root@debian:~# fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-user-auth.conf
...
Success, the total number of match is 54
...
```

It also shows me the right IPs and date/times.

But the jail doesn't detect a single failed login attempt:

```
root@debian:~# fail2ban-client status nginx-user-auth
Status for the jail: nginx-user-auth
|- filter
|  |- File list:        /var/log/nginx/error.log
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed:     0
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:
   `- Total banned:     0
```

Other jails are working perfectly. And I have absolutely no clue where I made the mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Came across your example here, from which I inspired and used in my config, and it's working.
Mind the "**:**" in the first regex, after user .*?, and also add a second "failregex" suffix for the other regex.

`/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-auth.conf

failregex = user .*?: password mismatch, client: <HOST>

failregex = user .*? was not found in .*?, client: <HOST>`

`` Status for the jail: nginx-auth

|- filter

|  |- File list:        /var/log/nginx/error.log

|  |- Currently failed: 0

|  `- Total failed:     6

`- action

   |- Currently banned: 1

   |  `- IP list:       x.x.x.x

   `- Total banned:     1 ``

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening due to a bug in the version of fail2ban you have installed. I had the exact same problem with the version of fail2ban distributed with my version of Ubuntu (0.8.4). After installing fail2ban 0.8.10 from source, my nginx filter started to work.

There are a couple of issues on the fail2ban Github page that mention this problem (they are closed and fixed now).